# How to ensure any of application's Activities which is currently in foreground to receive a message

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, localbroadcastmanager, sticky-broadcast

I want any of application's `Activities` which is currently in foreground to receive a message.

So I'm sending a [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to distribute a message across my application. Then my idea was to have `BaseActivity` which all other `Activities` must extend. In the `BaseActivity` in `onResume` a receiver is registered ([`registerReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29)) for the message and it's unregistered ([`unregisterReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver))) in `onPause`.

This will work always but not when the message is distributed just in the time slot when transition between `Activities` is happening and the previous `Activity` is after it's `onPause` and next `Activity` is before its `onResume`.

So I wanted to use [`sendStickyBroadcast`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) so that the message will wait until some `Activity` did not take it out, but I see

> This method was deprecated in API level 21.

**So how to ensure any of application's Activities which is currently in foreground to receive a message.**

Comment: what component (and when) sends a local broadcasts?

Comment: Why does it matter? Let's assume it's some background job and it's not send too often, once in a few minutes.

Comment: for example if it is a Service then bind to it

Answer (score 1):

> This method was deprecated in API level 21.

Still, you can use if for a while. Deprecation does not automatically make feature unuseable.

> So how to ensure any of application's Activities which is currently in foreground to receive a message.

You can switch to event bus lib like [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and have activity state/lifecycle completely irrelevant

Comment: "Still, you can use if for a while. Deprecation does not automatically make feature unuseable." OK but deprecation is a big warning sign. Furthermore it was not deprecated without reason, especially as the comment in docs says "They provide no security (anyone can access them), no protection (anyone can modify them), and many other problems". But yeah, some sort of event bus whould do the trick.